# "tsc" command showing, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm new in typescript,
I tried to convert typescript file into javascript file, by running command `tsc filename.ts`.
But It's showing error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:93
  for (let i = startIndex ?? 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
```

I tried to install node to it's latest version.

Comment: just a pure guess: old version of nodejs that didn't support "??" operator yet?

Comment: ^^ came into node in version 14.0 over 3 years ago ... so, you're using an old node version that's for sure

Comment: This is happening to me right now with Visual Studio 2019 which always uses its own private `node.exe` at `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node.exe"` - which is version 12.20 - I'm looking to see how to configure MSBuild to use a specific node.exe version but not found a solution yet.

Comment: I've filed a GitHub issue about this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54686

Comment: Please add the contents of `tsconfig.json` to your question.

Comment: @Dai there is no issue to report, The oldest still supported version of Node, v16 (which will be dead in a few weeks) has support for `??`. As does the version before that. And the version before that. The solution is "use any version of Node that's v14 or above", which really means "use Node 18 or Node 20, depending on whether you need maintenance LTS or active LTS"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't know how you can say "Visual Studio 2019 doesn't work with TypeScript 5.1" is not an issue.

Comment: I can say it really easily, because VS2019 predates the `??` operator _existing_, so of course it's going to fail. That's like wanting TS to work _at all_ in VS2012. The current version of Visual Studio is VS2022, so update VS. TypeScript moves just as fast as JavaScript: keep your tooling up to date.

Comment: I ran into the same issue after installing nodejs on ubuntu via apt. I was following the getting started with Apollo server docs (for graphql + typescript). Downgrading the typescript version did the trick. But i guess in a prod/real dev env (I'm just messing around) you should strongly prefer upgrading your NODE

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, [Veerendra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76687437/12075306) is right, typescript now [requires](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#breaking-changes) node 14.17 as "Minimum Runtime Requirements". What I've just done is uninstall `nodejs`, `npm`, `typescript`, ... completely from my system (Ubuntu 22) and then installed the latest LTS version of nodejs using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). Go directly to [this line in the readme](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating) to see the commands to install `nvm`.

With `nvm` you can choose any version of `nodejs` you want to install. Installing a particular version of `nodejs` also gets you `npm`. I chose to install `v18.17.0`,

```
$ nvm install v18.17.0
```

then installed the packages using `npm` as usual and now the command `tsc` works fine.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue with `TypeScript` 5.1.6 and Node 12.x version.

Because of this combination you get this issue. I downgraded my `TypeScript` to 4.9.5 and it worked for me fine.

Please check the image below for reference:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html

[image: Screenshot of Change Log]

Comment: Support for `??` was added in Node 14, which is *several versions older than the current LTS*. The solution is to upgrade Node, not downgrade TS.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue in-spite of using node v18 as suggested in link - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#es2020-and-node-js-14-17-as-minimum-runtime-requirements

I downgraded my typescript version from 5.1 to 5 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as the original post.

I realised our pipeline was using node 12, and thus had to downgrade to typescript 4.9.5 and that solved it.